# ¿Como puedo comparar un binario de Datos con GridFs en MongoDb?

Tags: c#, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, meteor

estoy utilizando C# y MongoDB como motor de base de datos.
En mi aplicación guardo la Huella del Usuario utilizado las siguientes lineas en C#.

```
         var id3 = ObjectId.Empty;
            using (var file = File.OpenRead(rutaArchivo))
            {
                id3 = gridFs.AddFile(file, ruta);//Obtengo el id de mi  griffile mongo 
                 //y lo guarda en mi base de datos
            }
```

Lo guarda de la siguiente manera en mi Fs.Files:
[image: fsfiles]

Asi mismo para mi Fs.Chunks

[image: fschunks]

Lo que no puedo hacer hasta ahora es comparar la huella del usuario con cada una guardada en mi base de datos.